given the apk for an app, how can I discover what devices are and are not supported?
As per the title: if I manage to download an APK, it'll have some file(s) that list what devices are compatible or not (things like android version, screen size and other restrictions)
What is/what are these files?

See app manifest// How to get to manifest?

See my answer to a similar question: How to get the real reasons for an incompatible app/.apk?
